# How can I make sure empty textboxes text are entered into the db as DBNull?

Tags: ms-access, parameters, textbox, oledb, dbnull

I have an array of 18 textboxes, how can I specify which textbox is empty so that I can pass through `DBNull` into my parameters to my database access layer? I am using OleDb with Ms Access

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution that would allow roundtripping of NULLs distict from zero-length strings.

```
// <custom:NullableTextBox runat="server" id="Field1" />
// In code behind bind & unbind using Field1.NullableValue instead of Field1.Text
// In web config, update pages/controls as such with MyApp replaced with the 
// assembly name of your app
// <pages>
//      <controls>
//          <add  tagPrefix="custom" namespace="Custom" assembly="MyApp"/>
//     </controls>
//  </pages>
public class NullableTextBox :TextBox
{
    public object NullableValue
    {
        set
        {
            ViewState["IsDbNull"] = DBNull.Value==value;
            Text = value.ToString();
        }
        get
        {
            bool isNull = false;
            if (ViewState["IsDbNull"] != null)
            {
                isNull = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["IsDbNull"]);
            }

            if (isNull
                    && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text.Trim()))
            {
                return DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```